Line in on Ubuntu 24.04 or is DIGITUS Audio Adapter DA-70777 a possible match?
I have problems with line in and as an alternative solution I tried DIGITUS Audio Adapter DA-70777, but I can't make heads or tails of it.
It appears in Audacity, but it sounds like some setting is missing.
Can anyone help with line in setting (motherboard) or settings for the DA-71777?
